# Calling a component from a normal method?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to do a very simple thing of calling a component from a function in a functional component.
For example :

```
const BillingScreen = (props) => {

    const [barCodes, setBarCodes] = useState(new Set());
    const [billItems, setBillItems] = useState(new Map());

    useEffect(() => {
        barCodes.forEach(barCode => {
            if (!billItems.has(barCode)) {
                setBillItems(billItems => new Map(billItems).set(barCode, {...itemForBarcode, quantity : 1, price : itemForBarcode.price, totalPrice : itemForBarcode.price}))
            }
        })
    }, [barCodes, billItems])

    const addBarCode = ({barCodeType, barCode}) => {
        
        if (barCodes.has(barCode)) {
            //TODO need to call this when this condition passes. 
            return <QuantityModelScreen isUpdate={true} item={billItems.get(barCode)} handlSubmit={updateProduct}/> 
        }
        else {
            setBarCodes(barCodes => new Set(barCodes).add(barCode))
        }
    }

    
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <View style = {styles.barCode}>
                <BarCodeScannerComponent addBarCode = {(barCode) => addBarCode(barCode)} />
            </View>
    )
}
```

I want to call the  component whenever the if condition enters the block.

It could be a very basic thing which I'm missing :)

TIA. :)

Comment: Need to see the implementation of BarCodeScannerComponent

Comment: It just calls the addBarCode() method with the parameters as shown above. I don't have the rights to publish that code here :)

Comment: Seems there is some missing code... where is `updateProduct` defined? What is `addBarCode` returning JSX to? It also seems you've missed passing a `barCodeType` value to `addBarCode` in the `addBarCode` callback prop of `BarCodeScannerComponent`. When you say, "Call a component" can you be a bit more specific? In react you don't "call" components, they are rendered into the returned JSX.

Comment: @DrewReese, we can ignore the missing code and the missing parameters also(though, you're true in all the above observations :) )

The question,  "What is addBarCode returning JSX to ?", is something that's the main attraction of the show. addBarCode is called from the <BarCodeScannerComponent> and it doesn't need to return anything. I just didn't know what to do here. I just want to fire up another component from addBarCode() method to when the if condition is satisfied. (return just takes away compilation error, just ignore it and help) TIA.

Comment: What do you mean by "fire up another component from addBarCode() method to when the if condition is satisfied"? If `addBarCode` doesn't need to return anything then perhaps return `null` for the early return. Or are you ***trying*** to render the returned JSX somewhere? It still isn't clear what you are trying to do. In react you don't directly "invoke" components, you pass them to React and React handles "invocation" and lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

I added a state 'isBar' to manage whether or not to display the component.
Inside the 'if' statement I set 'isBar' to true (or false...),
And at least- I show the component only if the variable 'isBar' is true.

```
const BillingScreen = (props) => {

const [barCodes, setBarCodes] = useState(new Set());
const [billItems, setBillItems] = useState(new Map());
const [isBar, setIsBar] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    barCodes.forEach(barCode => {
        if (!billItems.has(barCode)) {
            setBillItems(billItems => new Map(billItems).set(barCode, {...itemForBarcode, quantity : 1, price : itemForBarcode.price, totalPrice : itemForBarcode.price}))
        }
    })
}, [barCodes, billItems])

const addBarCode = ({barCodeType, barCode}) => {
    
    if (barCodes.has(barCode)) {
        setIsBar(true);
        return <QuantityModelScreen isUpdate={true} item={billItems.get(barCode)} handlSubmit={updateProduct}/> 
    }
    else {
        setIsBar(false)
        setBarCodes(barCodes => new Set(barCodes).add(barCode))
    }
}


return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.barCode}>
            {isBar &&<yourComponent/>}
            <BarCodeScannerComponent addBarCode = {(barCode) => addBarCode(barCode)} />
        </View>
)
```

}

Comment: what if we want the data (for example, barCode and barCodeType from addBarCode method) to be used inside <yourComponent> ?

Comment: You can send it by property, like this: <yourComponent isBar={isBar} />
and use in the component as "props.isBar"

Comment: To be more clear, I have a variable that I find doing some operation inside my addBarCode() method, i.e barCode. Now I want this barCode value to be passed inside <yourComponent>. Remember, the barCode variable is local to addBarCode() method.

Comment: barCode is not loacl variable because you pass it from the global state. You have global state 'barCode' in your parent component, so you can use it in his children - 'yourComponent' and also 'BarCodeScannerComponent'.
It will change automatically in the children when changing the parent.